# A finite Fibonacci sum

Tags: real-analysis, fibonacci-numbers, sumset

Is there a closed form for
$$
A(n)=\sum_{k=1}^n\binom{n}{k}\frac{F_k}k
$$
A closed form that is not in terms of two hypergeometric functions.

Comment: The $n$-th Fibonacci number is $\phi^n+(1-\phi)^n$ where $\phi$ is the golden ratio. So your sum is equal to the sum of two sums of geometric progressions.

Comment: Please use MathJax to render the math.

Comment: @JCAA That's not quite right, it should be $\frac{\phi^n-(1-\phi)^n}{\sqrt{5}}$

Comment: @Graviton: That is not very important But the OP in the edited text also has $/k$ which makes a difference,

Comment: The Wolfram alpha gives the answer as a sum of two expressions involving hypergeom functions. Why do you think anybody can beat Wolfram?

Comment: Instead of Fibonacci numbers $F_k$ try first something simpler, say, $2^k$.

Comment: because Wolfram does NOT have all the answers

Comment: Fun fact: $$\sum_{k=1}^n\binom{n}{k}\frac{F_k}{k+1}=\frac{F_{2n+1}-1}{n+1}$$ But $k+1$ instead of $k$ in the denominator makes a hell of a difference, of course.

Comment: Also interesting: $$\sum_{k=1}^n\binom{n}{k}\frac{F_k}k=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{F_{2k}}{k}$$ It's not a closed form, though.

Comment: Thank you professor vector. I do have both of those results you quote.